# Как обеспечить взаимодействие между user conrol в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть главное окно MainWindow по нажатию в меню в гриде отрисовываем 1 usercontrol, в этом user control есть кнопка по нажатию которой, надо нарисовать 2 usercontrol, первый стереть

Comment: И ваши попытки? В чем трудности?

Comment: Пробовал создавать статическую переменную которая меняла свое значение на true, потом MainWindow.cs где вызываю первый UserCntrol проверять это поле и отрисовывать второй, но чтото без успехов

Comment: Вы умеете пользоваться привязками (про MVVM не спрашиваю)? Знаете как должен работать WPF проект?